# Run function on specified stack frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to execute function on specified stack frame.

It is successfully executed if function was declared on this frame, but if I'm trying to run function on another frame interpreter gives me such error:

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

For example:

```
> f1 <- function(x) {
+ x + 1
+ }
> x <- c(100:110)
> sys.frame(0)$f1(x) -- OK
 [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111
> debug(f1)
> f1(c(1:10))
debugging in: f1(c(1:10))
debug at #1: {
    x + 1
}
Browse[2]> n
debug at #2: x + 1
Browse[2]> sys.frame(1)$f1(x) -- FAIL
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Could you tell me please how to fix this?

Comment: What about `eval(f1(x), envir = sys.frame(1))`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Try to execute `eval(f1(x), envir = sys.frame(0))`, it gives me `[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11` instead of `[1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111`